# Linux eth0 is down, can't up it

Tags: linux

I do have a vps server. It's not too good but I use it only for teamspeak. Recently I got a massage from provider that my service is suspended becuase of some sort of sync flood attack. I don't know why. Nevermind. Now I can't connect to it through the Internet. I can only use remote console. I want to up eth0 but it still shows it's down. I can't set it up with ifup eth0. I provide needed informations.

[image: 3]

[image: interfaces file]

Answer (score 5):

The OS thinks the interface is UP (it says so on the first line of output of the `ip` command).

However the status says `NO-CARRIER` which likely means it's been disabled on the parent host.  You need to work with your VPS provider to get the interface re-enabled.

Comment: So you think I need to contact them?

Comment: Yes.  They suspended your service, you need to talk to them.

Comment: ehhh I don't even know where, nvm, thanks then  I'll let know if I know something new